# Using Editor in textarea rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At this time I'm using this editor http://cksource.com/ckeditor
The thing is when I access in the new form the textarea doesn't work but if I Update the new form in the browser it works OK

My partial is like that

```
<%= simple_form_for [@version, @documento], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <td><%= f.input :name, 
                :label      => false,
                :input_html => {:style => 'width: 380px;'} %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Tipo de Documento</th>
        <td>
            <%= f.association :tipo,
                :label      => false,
                :required   => true,
                :input_html => {:class => 'span2'}
            %>
            <%= link_to 'Nuevo',new_tipo_path, :remote => true %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Descripcion</th>
        <td><%= f.input :descripcion, 
                :label      => false, 
                :input_html => {:class => "ckeditor", :id => "descripcion"} %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :value => 'Guardar Documento' %>
    <%= link_to 'Cancelar', version_documentos_path(@version), :class => 'btn' %>
</div>
```

What could I do to fix this problem ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure just what you're seeing, and there's no errors listed in your post so not enough information to go on but your form looks OK.

If you're not opposed to it, you can use the gem for ckeditor.  It's just a wrapper around the javascripts to make sure everything works in the asset pipeline without interfering with your form.

https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails

3 steps

`gem 'ckeditor_rails'` Add the gem to the Gemfile

`//= require ckeditor-jquery` Include the js in application.js

`<%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'ckeditor' %>` Add the class to your text area input

Comment: I did what you told me but continue the same problem, I need to update the new form to use the ckeditor, I'm working with rails 4.0

Comment: I just did a test with vanilla rails 4 but everything worked fine - you can see the example project I did to test if it helps, though it sounds like you have some deeper issue that is yet undescribed: https://github.com/trh/rails4_ckeditor_example

Comment: I found the solution but is not so good, because i needed to uninstall the gem turbolinks, that gem was the problem, you know how can I use it with turbolinks too ??, Or maybe configuring a link_to that doesn't work with turbolinks in the same project...

Comment: I found the solution, i just make a div this way <div data-no-turbolink>Here is the link what I dont want working with turbolinks</div>, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, like I said in the last answer the problem was turbolinks

In that case when we dont want to use a link working with turbolinks we just need to make a div this way

```
<div data-no-turbolink>
  <%= link_to 'Nuevo Documento', new_version_documento_path(@version), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to 'Atras', versions_path , :class => 'btn'%></div>
```

So this link doesn't work with turbo links but the ckeditor gem doesn't have any problem